# Room Persistance Library Query COLLATE LOCALIZED not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, android-room

I'm using the new [Room Persistance Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) released at this years Google I/O and it's working great so far, but somehow it's not possible to order the results with **UNICODE** or **LOCALIZED**. The only thing working is **NOCASE** which is useless in my case.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality yet?

```
@Dao
public interface ContactDao { 

    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY lastName COLLATE LOCALIZED")
    Flowable<List<Contact>> getAll();
}
```

If I build the Query like above i get an error:

```
Error:(21, 29) error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] 
SQL error or missing database (no such collation sequence: LOCALIZED)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, to use `COLLATE LOCALIZED`, you need to declare that as part of a column constraint in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. It would appear that you can use a `Migration` to code your own `CREATE TABLE` statement, though it is unclear to me how to create a `Migration` for the initial table creation (vs. an upgrade). I do not know if you were the one who filed [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62007004), but I'd keep an eye on it.

Comment: Hi, did you fix it?

Comment: Not really... at the moment i just sort the list before i use is.

 `Collections.sort(nameOfYourList) { o1, o2 -> Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).compare(o1.lastName, o2.lastName) }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**you have to use these version of room**

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

after updating your room gradle line

you can use this feature

@ColumnInfo(collate = ColumnInfo.NOCASE)

Comment: yes! This question is pretty old, but in newer versions this feature is finally implemented.

Comment: @ColumnInfo(collate = ColumnInfo.NOCASE)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why LOCALIZED collation is not implemented (in Room version 1.0.0) when it is in documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ColumnInfo.html#LOCALIZED). I found this issue report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68925249 which is marked as fixed - but it is not released probably.

So there is ugly workaround as CommonsWare commented in question - define it in CREATE statement. This can be implemented by callback in database builder. But there is problem - we must using create table because sqlite do not support alter collate. And because table exists yet in callback, we must delete this table.

There is my implementation (in Kotlin) - create statement must copy entity class definition also with indexes:

```
@Database(entities = [(LocalityItem::class)], version = AppDatabase.DB_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun localityDao(): LocalityDao

    companion object {
        const val DB_NAME : String = "app_db"
        const val DB_VERSION : Int = 1

        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        private val CALLBACK: Callback = object : Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE `locality` ")
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `locality` ("
                        + " `id` INTEGER,"
                        + " `type` INTEGER,"
                        + " `name` TEXT COLLATE LOCALIZED, "
                        + " `row_index` INTEGER,"
                        + " `col_index` INTEGER,"
                        + " PRIMARY KEY(`id`)"
                        + ")")
                db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `index_locality_type` ON `locality` (`type`)")
                db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX `index_locality_name` ON `locality` (`name`)")
            }
        }

        fun getInstance(context : Context) : AppDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(AppDatabase::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            AppDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
                            .addCallback(CALLBACK)
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `COLLATE` at time of column define in following way,

`@ColumnInfo(collate = NOCASE) var name: String`

It is working fine for me.
No need to specify `COLLATE` in `Query`.

Also there is no `LOCALIZED` collate in `Room`